# How to prevent MediaWiki removing non default signatures?

Tags: configuration, mediawiki

We recently upgraded MediaWiki from 1.13.2 to 1.15.4. One of the side effects is that people's signatures are automatically deleted. That is, a signature added under MY PREFERENCES gets changed to match the Real Name field after a couple of minutes.

We set [$wgCleanSignatures = false](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCleanSignatures) in LocalSettings.php but this does not change the behaviour.

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

**Update:** it might help to add some more details.

In MY PREFERENCES I write:

```
[[User:MyName|<span style="color:lightseagreen">My Name</span>]] ([[User talk:MyName|<span style="color:lightseagreen">Talk</span>]])
```

My signature on a talk page is therefore:

```
--[[User:MyName|<span style="color:lightseagreen">My Name</span>]] ([[User talk:MyName|<span style="color:lightseagreen">Talk</span>]]) <time date stamp>
```

After one hour, the preference reverts to:

```
My Name
```

And my signature becomes:

```
--My Name <time date stamp>
```

Comment: Are you using external authentication by chance, such as ldap?

Comment: @pablo - yes! But this has not changed since the upgrade. We modified LDAP log in so that people do not get a log in screen but automatically get a new user made when they first log in to the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

This should an issue with using external authentication.  When a user logs in it updates their attributes, and I am guessing during this process during the upgrade it is also updating the users signature, modify your code as needed.

You can see from the below how it updates.

Also check here, there is some chat about if you are using auto login it looks like signature is updated with username, youll need to mod the code.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk:LDAP_Authentication/Archive_2#Signature_with_Real_Name

In LdapAuthentication.php

```
/**
 * When a user logs in, update user with information from LDAP.
 *
 * @param User $user
 * @access public
 * TODO: fix the setExternalID stuff
 */
function updateUser( &$user ) {
    global $wgLDAPRetrievePrefs;
    global $wgLDAPUseLDAPGroups;
    global $wgLDAPUniqueBlockLogin, $wgLDAPUniqueRenameUser;

    $this->printDebug( "Entering updateUser", NONSENSITIVE );

    if ($this->authFailed) {
        $this->printDebug( "User didn't successfully authenticate, exiting.", NONSENSITIVE );
        return;
    }

    $saveSettings = false;

    //If we aren't pulling preferences, we don't want to accidentally
    //overwrite anything.
    if ( isset( $wgLDAPRetrievePrefs[$_SESSION['wsDomain']] ) && $wgLDAPRetrievePrefs[$_SESSION['wsDomain']] ) {
        $this->printDebug( "Setting user preferences.", NONSENSITIVE );

        if ( '' != $this->lang ) {
            $user->setOption( 'language', $this->lang );
        }
        if ( '' != $this->nickname ) {
            $user->setOption( 'nickname', $this->nickname );
        }
        if ( '' != $this->realname ) {
            $user->setRealName( $this->realname );
        }
        if ( '' != $this->email ) {
            $user->setEmail( $this->email );
        }
        if ( ( isset( $wgLDAPUniqueBlockLogin[$_SESSION['wsDomain']] ) && $wgLDAPUniqueBlockLogin[$_SESSION['wsDomain']] )
            || ( isset( $wgLDAPUniqueRenameUser[$_SESSION['wsDomain']] ) && $wgLDAPUniqueRenameUser[$_SESSION['wsDomain']] ) ) {

            if ( '' != $this->externalid ) {
                $user->setExternalID( $this->externalid );
            }
        }

        $saveSettings = true;
    }

    if ( isset( $wgLDAPUseLDAPGroups[$_SESSION['wsDomain']] ) && $wgLDAPUseLDAPGroups[$_SESSION['wsDomain']] ) {
        $this->printDebug( "Setting user groups.", NONSENSITIVE );
        $this->setGroups( $user );

        $saveSettings = true;
    }

    if ( $saveSettings ) {
        $this->printDebug( "Saving user settings.", NONSENSITIVE );
        $user->saveSettings();
    }
}
```

Comment: @pablo - you might be on to something here. Our authentication is re-checked every hour or so, so this must be the reason. But I don't know what to do with the information you've provided.

Comment: can you paste your ldapauthentication.php source code somewhere like http://pastebin.com/

Comment: @pablo - will do but cannot right now - in 24 hours. Should I be looking for any particular part?

Comment: look at the function above and see if you see something about signature, if you paste the whole thing somewhere i can have a look.

Comment: @pablo - done http://pastebin.com/wgJf4FCz great tip to use pastebin, thanks! BTW - this is an *additional* file - the MediaWiki LDAP files are not changed.

Comment: thanks, can you post the LDAP files, there are different versions of them so need to see the exact one to give you the best advice.

Comment: @pablo: both are MW 1.15.4. Here is the code: LdapAuthentication.php: http://pastebin.com/zwyymEcJ LdapAutoAuthentication.php: http://pastebin.com/3qUhyBrh Thanks!

Comment: @pablo - I have not awarded you the bounty as your answer was incomplete and this discussion was never finished. If you get back to me and complete this question I will create a new bounty and award it to you. Sorry, but the time was up.

Comment: sorry havent had time, will take a look today i hope.

Comment: @pabloe - thx. In the meantime I deleted the answer I gave because it turned out to be incorrect.